# Où dit-on « kermesse »?

Tags: vocabulaire, régionalismes, néerlandais, emprunts

Il y a deux semaines je passais mes vacances dans un hameau qui portait le nom « Les Trois Épis », au nord-est de la France, où j’ai aperçu le mot « kermesse ». Je savais déjà que cet emprunt du néerlandais était utilisé aux endroits septentrionaux de la France, mais je m'attendais pas à ce qu'il apparaîsse si loin des Pays-Bas. Je pensais plutôt que ce mot était seulement connu aux alentours de Dunkerque, à la cime absolue du pays.

Ce mot, est-il répandu jusqu’aux confins du pays, ou y a-t-il des bornes pour son emploi quand même ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le mot *kermesse* a dépassé depuis plus d'un siècle le seuil des départements du Nord et du Pas de Calais pour être employé dans toute la France (pour le Canada et autres pays francophones je ne peux rien dire).

Il peut désigner des événements de nature différente :

Guy de Maupassant (*La vie errante*,1890) l'a employé de façon littéraire pour désigner l'Expostion Universelle de de 1878 qui a eu lieu à Paris)

> Peu m'importe, d'ailleurs, la tour Eiffel. Elle ne fut que le phare d'une kermesse internationale, selon l'expression consacré dont le souvenir me hantera comme le cauchemar, comme la vision réalisée de l’horrible spectacle que peut donner à un homme dégoûté la foule humaine qui s'amuse.

Dans le nord de la France*, au Luxembourg et en Belgique flamande le mot peut encore avoir le sens de fête patronale du village, mais ailleurs il désigne en général une simple fête foraine, comme la [kermesse de Bruxelles](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foire_du_Midi) ou les foires-kermesses de l'est de la France, la plus célèbre étant celle de [Mulhouse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foire_kermesse_de_Mulhouse). Ce peut être un simple rassemblement villageois convivial dans le but de partager et échanger, même si [l'idée de commerce est souvent présente](http://www.apeas.fr/Kermesse-paysanne.html).

La [kermesse des écoles](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermesse_des_%C3%A9coles_fran%C3%A7aises) est une événement qui a lieu en fin d'année scolaire, encore très présent dans les écoles françaises, et qui est destiné à récolter des fonds qui vont compléter ceux de [la caisse des écoles](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caisse_des_%C3%A9coles).

<sup>* Régions où survit encore le [flamand français](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamand_fran%C3%A7ais) et où l'étymologie du mot, *Kerkmisse* « Messe de l'église », est encore comprise.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Le mot est complètement entré dans la langue française, et se comprend partout.

Néamoins selon le [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/kermesse/45455), le terme "non limité géographiquement" est plus général et décrit une « fête en plein air, souvent au bénéfice de quelque chose » alors que dans les Flandres, c'est plus précisément une fête paroissiale.